# Architectural Patterns Pub/Sub Scaling and Disaster Recovery

Tags: architecture, scalability, load-balancing, publish-subscribe

We will have a source system broadcasting messages over a JMS compliant pub/sub infrastructure.  For the majority of messages published the subscribers will be GUI applications updating a screen with the data in the message.

One of the subscribers, however, will be a translation service.  For certain messages published the translation service will translate the message into a different format and publish it onto a secondary messaging infrastructure owned by a different part of the enterprise.

How can I scale out my translation service and provide, ideally, active-active fault tolerance?  Some notes:

- The messages need to be published onto the secondary messaging infrastructure in order.
- The messages must only be published once onto the secondary messaging infrastructure.

Basically, how do I make sure that only 1 translation service subscriber responds to the messages?  Do I need to switch to a queue based system (but my GUIs will still need pub/sub semantics)?

Note that the translation service will bet a .Net 3.5 application hosted in Windows Server 2003.  We have F5 Network's BigIP LTM/GTMs available.

Any more details required please ask/comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/toc.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at reliable messaging in wcf. Perhaps it helps